# How to deserialize a list inside of a list with list type Interface?

Tags: c#, json.net

While deserializing, I get this error:

> Error getting value from 'tasksToDo' on 'StudentHousingFramework.Modules.Room'.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm trying to deserialize a list of interfaces that have a list of type interface (different ones) inside.

`tasksToDo` is a `List<Interface>` on the class and it's, to my understanding, what's causing the issue.

The way I deserialize is via this classes:

```
public void Serealise<T>(string nameList, List<T> list)
{
        path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, nameList);
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
        }); ;

        File.WriteAllText(path, jsonString);
}

public List<IAccount>? DeserealiseRoom(string list)
{
    path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, list);

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        var file = File.ReadAllText(path);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IAccount>>(file, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ReferenceLoopHandling= ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                TypeNameHandling= TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            });
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is the class `room` that inherits from the interface that characterises the list:

```
public class Room : IAccount
{
    public Room()
    {
    }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<ITask> tasksToDo 
    {
        get
        {
            return factory.manager.tasks.FindAll(w => w.claimer == this);
        }
    }

    public Login login { get; set; }
    public bool isOccupied { get; private set; } = true;
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Room " + id;
        }
    }
    
    public Json json { get; set; } = new Json();
    private Factory factory { get; set; }

    public Room(Factory factory, int id)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.id = id;
        login = new Login();
    }
}
```

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: What is 'tasksToDo' exactly?

Comment: @HéctorM. tasksToDo is a List inside of the class Room

Comment: I see, and it seems that among these `factory.manager.tasks` there is one that is not assigned, so it is always `null`

Comment: @HéctorM. that actually is a good observation. Thank you so much!

Comment: @HéctorM. well I tried to reverse it and it still doesn't work. Even if tasks is assigned... the same error occurs

Comment: It's hard to diagnose why this error is happening without looking at more of your project and the JSON file you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249819/discussion-between-hector-m-and-citrusboy).